# BEA-141297 - Could not get the server file lock

Tags: oracle, server, locking, weblogic

Following error is encountered when trying to start Oracle Weblogic Server:

```
<Info> <Management> <BEA-141297> <Could not get the server file lock. Ensure that another server is not running in the same directory. Retrying for another 60 seconds.>
```

How do I overcome this error and start the server?

Comment: remember to kill java.exe in the task manager

Comment: What is your question? This looks like you tried to answer it within the question itself. Please consider [answering your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The error means that there is a file lock that could not be released, as the server was previously not shut down correctly.

In this case you must follow the next steps:

- Navigate to `tmp` folder in your `$DOMAIN_HOME` directory. (for example: `C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\mydomain\servers\AdminServer\tmp`)
- Delete the lock file for the server instance, `AdminServer.lok`
- Check if there are any `java.exe` processes are running, which should not be there. If there are any, they would have to be killed.
- Restart your server

Comment: I don't see any `AdminServer.lok` file at this location, I am still seeing the same error.

Comment: Same problem, same solution, worked for me. Thanks!